# Why is text being positioned above the table?

Tags: tables

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{blue}{\color{LightSteelBlue3}}
\newcommand{\foo}{\color{LightSteelBlue3}\makebox[0pt]{\textbullet}\hskip-0.5pt\vrule width 1pt\hspace{\labelsep}}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{chronology}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command for the horizontal lines, change thickness here

\center % Center everything on the page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADING SECTIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\textsc{\LARGE University of Abertay}\\[1.5cm] % Name of your university/college
\textsc{\Large BSC Web Development}\\[0.5cm] % Major heading such as course name

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \huge \bfseries Key social media concepts, technologies and strategies}\\[0.4cm] % Title of your document
\HRule \\[1.5cm]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AUTHOR SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
Joshua \textsc{Dempsey} % Your name
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
Shona \textsc{Irvine} % Supervisor's Name
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[2cm]

% If you don't want a supervisor, uncomment the two lines below and remove the section above
%\Large \emph{Author:}\\
%John \textsc{Smith}\\[3cm] % Your name

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DATE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

{\large \today}\\[2cm] % Date, change the \today to a set date if you want to be precise

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LOGO SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{logo.png} % Include a department/university logo - this will require the graphicx package

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\vfill % Fill the rest of the page with whitespace

\end{titlepage}


\begin{abstract}
The aim of this research is to establish the history behind social media and examine its evolution through the ages to the current day. I will also reflect on social media's use in society today and examine the ways in which social media negatively and positively affects our lives.

To conduct my research  I will utilise numerous third party websites \\- all of which will be referenced at the end of the document. I will also rely on personal anecdotes from myself and friends. Any information not referenced can be assumed to be a personal anecdote.
\end{abstract}

\newpage

\section{Evolution of social media}

Whether it's \textbf{\textit{"checking in"}} to a restaurant they are visiting, posting pictures from a holiday, live streaming a sports event or communicating with relatives on the other side of the world, it's fair to say that most people do not appreciate the history behind social media and take it for granted.

Behind all of the worlds most popular social media applications however, lies a great deal of history, dating all the way back to the stone ages. Below is a time line detailing the spectacular and fast paced history and evolution of social media, and underneath a brief description of the events included on the time line.
\newpage
\begin{table}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue3}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false, font=blue, labelfont=sc, labelsep=quad}
\caption{Timeline of Social Media}\vskip -1.5ex
\begin{tabular}{@{\,}r <{\hskip 4pt} !{\foo} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{7cm}}

Late 70's & Bulletin Board Systems \textbf{\textit{"BBS"}} were initially conceived \\
1979 & Usenet was developed by Tom Truscott and Jim Ellis \\
1980's & Compuserve and Prodigy were launched \\
1985 & Genie was created and launched by General Electric \\
1988 & IRC was created \\
1990's & ICQ was developed in the mid 1990's \\
1997 & Six degrees was launched \\
1997 - 2001 & AsianAvenue, MiGente, BlackPlanet \\
1999 & LiveJournal was created\\
2000 & Many social games were becoming increasingly popular \\
2002 & Friendster was launched \\
2003 & Hi5, LinkedIn, Myspace, PhotoBucket were all launched \\
2004 & Facebook, Orkut, Flickr were launched \\
2005 & YouTube, Reddit were launched \\ 
2006 & Twitter, uStream were launched \\
2007 & Tumblr was launched \\
2010 & Pinterest launched \\
2011 & Snapchat, Google+ launched \\
2012 & Dating app Tinder launched \\
2015 & Periscope launched

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

As we can see, the history and evolution is one that is long and chequered. The timeline above is by no means exhaustive and is only showing the main applications and services which people have used the world over - there is a whole world of smaller, more localised applications and services that are out-with the remit of this report. 
\end{document}
```

Above is some code for a report I'm working on. The thing that I'm confused with is this: in the Latex document the table appears before the paragraph that begins with "As we can see, the history and evolution is one that is long and chequered...", however the output has this flipped, so the text comes before the table. I've tried Googling and looked for solutions online, but being a new user to Latex,  I'm not quite sure where to begin.

The code is hosted here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/cjzzszzprptk

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`table` environments cannot break across pages. Your `table` (which consists of a caption and a `tabular` environment, with the right-hand column "only" 7cm wide, forcing quite a few of the lines to "wrap") is too tall to fit on the page that already contains a section header and two paragraphs. The best LaTeX can do, then, is to place the `table` on a page all by itself. (That's what the "float" in "floating environment" means.)

If you don't want the tabular material to float in this manner and if you are OK with having a page break occur somewhere in the tabular material, you shouldn't use a `table`/`tabular` combination to begin with. Instead, look into using a `longtable` environment. The following code implements this suggestion. In the code below, I've done away with the title and abstract pages since they are not relevant for the topic at hand.

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}
\usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{blue}{\color{LightSteelBlue3}}
\newcommand{\foo}{\color{LightSteelBlue3}
    \makebox[0pt]{\textbullet}\hskip-0.5pt
    \vrule width 1pt
    \hspace{\labelsep}}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{chronology}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}

\begin{document}

\section{Evolution of social media}

Whether it's \textbf{\textit{``checking in''}} to a restaurant they are visiting, posting pictures from a holiday, live streaming a sports event or communicating with relatives on the other side of the world, it's fair to say that most people do not appreciate the history behind social media and take it for granted.

Behind all of the world's most popular social media applications, however, lies a great deal of history, dating all the way back to the stone age. Below is a time line detailing the spectacular and fast paced history and evolution of social media, and underneath a brief description of the events included on the time line.

\begingroup  
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}
\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue3}
\captionsetup{font=blue, labelfont=sc, labelsep=quad}
\begin{longtable}{r <{\hspace{4pt}} !{\foo} 
     >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{7cm}}
\caption{Timeline of Social Media\label{tab:1}}\\
\endfirsthead
\caption*{(Table \ref{tab:1}, continued)}\\
\endhead
\multicolumn{2}{r}{(continued)}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
Late 70's & Bulletin Board Systems \textbf{\textit{``BBS''}} initially conceived \\
1979 & Usenet developed by Tom Truscott and Jim Ellis \\
1980's & Compuserve and Prodigy launched \\
1985 & Genie created and launched by General Electric \\
1988 & IRC created \\
1990's & ICQ developed in the mid 1990's \\
1997 & Six degrees  launched \\
1997--2001 & AsianAvenue, MiGente, BlackPlanet \\
1999 & LiveJournal created\\
2000 & Many social games becoming increasingly popular \\
2002 & Friendster launched \\
2003 & Hi5, LinkedIn, Myspace, PhotoBucket all launched \\
2004 & Facebook, Orkut, Flickr launched \\
2005 & YouTube, Reddit launched \\ 
2006 & Twitter, uStream launched \\
2007 & Tumblr launched \\
2010 & Pinterest launched \\
2011 & Snapchat, Google+ launched \\
2012 & Dating app Tinder launched \\
2015 & Periscope launched\\
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

As we can see, the history and evolution are long and chequered. The timeline is by no means exhaustive, and it only shows the main applications and services which people have used the world over---there is a whole world of smaller, more localised applications and services that are out---with the remit of this report. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

I propose to use the `ltablex` package, which combines the possibilities of `tabularx` and `longtable`. In short the table can break across pages if necessary.

I supposed the `\newpage` commands were attempts to have the table appear were you wanted, so I took the liberty to rmove them. Also I replaced your programmers' quotes with typographical quotes.

Hopefully the result looks more like what you want:

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{blue}{\color{LightSteelBlue3}}
\newcommand{\foo}{\color{LightSteelBlue3}\makebox[0pt]{\textbullet}\hskip-0.5pt\vrule width 1pt\hspace{\labelsep}}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{chronology}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command for the horizontal lines, change thickness here
\usepackage{ltablex}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{titlepage}

  \centering % Center everything on the page

  %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  % HEADING SECTIONS
  %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  \textsc{\LARGE University of Abertay}\\[1.5cm] % Name of your university/college
  \textsc{\Large BSC Web Development}\\[0.5cm] % Major heading such as course name

  %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  % TITLE SECTION
  %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  \HRule \\[0.4cm]
  { \huge \bfseries Key social media concepts, technologies and strategies}\\[0.4cm] % Title of your document
  \HRule \\[1.5cm]

  %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  % AUTHOR SECTION
  %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft} \large
      \emph{Author:}\\
      Joshua \textsc{Dempsey} % Your name
    \end{flushleft}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{flushright} \large
      \emph{Supervisor:} \\
      Shona \textsc{Irvine} % Supervisor's Name
    \end{flushright}
  \end{minipage}\\[2cm]

  % If you don't want a supervisor, uncomment the two lines below and remove the section above
  %\Large \emph{Author:}\\
  %John \textsc{Smith}\\[3cm] % Your name

  %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  % DATE SECTION
  %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  {\large \today}\\[2cm] % Date, change the \today to a set date if you want to be precise

  %-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  % LOGO SECTION
  %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  %\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{logo.png} % Include a department/university logo - this will require the graphicx package

  %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  \vfill % Fill the rest of the page with whitespace

\end{titlepage}

\begin{abstract}
  The aim of this research is to establish the history behind social media and examine its evolution through the ages to the current day. I will also reflect on social media's use in society today and examine the ways in which social media negatively and positively affects our lives.

  To conduct my research I will utilise numerous third party websites -- all of which will be referenced at the end of the document. I will also rely on personal anecdotes from myself and friends. Any information not referenced can be assumed to be a personal anecdote.
\end{abstract}

\newpage

\section{Evolution of social media}

Whether it's \textbf{\textit{“checking in”}} to a restaurant they are visiting, posting pictures from a holiday, live streaming a sports event or communicating with relatives on the other side of the world, it's fair to say that most people do not appreciate the history behind social media and take it for granted.

Behind all of the worlds most popular social media applications however, lies a great deal of history, dating all the way back to the stone ages. Below is a time line detailing the spectacular and fast paced history and evolution of social media, and underneath a brief description of the events included on the time line.

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue3}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false, font=blue, labelfont=sc, labelsep=quad}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{\,}r <{\hskip 4pt} !{\foo} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}%p{10cm}
  \caption{Timeline of Social Media}\vspace*{-1ex}
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{\color{LightSteelBlue3}Timeline of Social Media\quad(continued)\vspace{1ex}}
  \endhead
  \multicolumn{2}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape To be continued}
  \endfoot
  \endlastfoot
  Late 70's & Bulletin Board Systems \textbf{\textit{“BBS”}} were initially conceived \\
  1979 & Usenet was developed by Tom Truscott and Jim Ellis \\
  1980's & Compuserve and Prodigy were launched \\
  1985 & Genie was created and launched by General Electric \\
  1988 & IRC was created \\
  1990's & ICQ was developed in the mid 1990's \\
  1997 & Six degrees was launched \\
  1997--2001 & AsianAvenue, MiGente, BlackPlanet \\
  1999 & LiveJournal was created \\
  2000 & Many social games were becoming increasingly popular \\
  2002 & Friendster was launched \\
  2003 & Hi5, LinkedIn, Myspace, PhotoBucket were all launched \\
  2004 & Facebook, Orkut, Flickr were launched \\
  2005 & YouTube, Reddit were launched \\
  2006 & Twitter, uStream were launched \\
  2007 & Tumblr was launched \\
  2010 & Pinterest launched \\
  2011 & Snapchat, Google+ launched \\
  2012 & Dating app Tinder launched \\
  2015 & Periscope launched
\end{tabularx}

As we can see, the history and evolution is one that is long and chequered. The timeline above is by no means exhaustive and is only showing the main applications and services which people have used the world over - there is a whole world of smaller, more localised applications and services that are out-with the remit of this report.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the present case, the table fits fully on one page; for more generality, though, you may want to indicate how the `\endhead`, `\endfoot`, and `\endlastfoot` directives might be set up so as to handle tables with page breaks.

Comment: @Mico: Oh yes! You're right my code was written from too strictly utilitarian point of view.